# Different messages for CompletionException under different minor versions of Java 8

Tags: java-8, java

I get a different output from the same code snippet under different minor version of java. I was not able to find the related ticket on the open jdk bug tracker.

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
completableFuture.complete("xxx");

completableFuture.thenCompose(str -> {
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
    completableFuture1.completeExceptionally(new Exception("hello"));
    return completableFuture1;
}).exceptionally(ex -> {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    return null;
}).get();
```

Output under JDK 1.8.0_25:

> hello

Output under JDK 1.8.0_102:

> java.lang.Exception: hello

Is the newer one a fix or a regression? What is the related ticket?

Comment: Isn't the exception message just there for humans? All necessary further values should be contained in the Exception itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug report [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068432) discussing this change. The key is in the Javadoc of [`CompletableFuture#thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-)

> Returns a **new `CompletionStage`** that, when this stage completes
>   normally, is executed with this stage as the argument to the supplied
>   function. **See the `CompletionStage` documentation for rules covering
>   exceptional completion.**

and and class documentation of `CompletionStage`

> In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with
>   an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring
>   its completion complete exceptionally as well, **with a
>   `CompletionException` holding the exception as its cause.**

That's what you see here. The `Function` you pass to `exceptionally` now receives a `CompletionException` holding the `Exception` that completed the triggering `CompletableFuture`.

The behavior you see now is the expected behavior.

You'll have to unwrap to get the cause of the exceptional completion

```
Throwable cause = ex.getCause(); // this is your Exception("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue and is been already fixed in 9 and backported to 8u60. You will see java.lang.Exception: hello from 8u60 onwards.